# What kind of 'product' is the 'product' in 'ionic product of water'?

Tags: equilibrium, water, ions, terminology

My language has different words for **product** (=the result of a process) and **product** (=the sum of multiplied quantities), so I need to know the right meaning to choose the right word.

Which of the meanings above is present in the English term '*ionic product of water*' ($K_\mathrm{w}$)?

This definition from http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/kw.html seems to suggest it is a *sum of multiplied quantities*:

> The units of $K_\mathrm{w}$: $K_\mathrm{w}$ is found **by multiplying two concentration terms together**. Each of these has the units of $\mathrm{mol~dm^{-3}}$. Multiplying $\mathrm{mol~dm^{-3}} \times \mathrm{mol~dm^{-3}}$ gives you the units above.

However, the use of the verb *produce* in this sentence from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water suggests something that is produced as a *result of a process*:

> According to the theories of Svante Arrhenius, this must be due to the presence of ions. The ions are **produced** by the self-ionization reaction $\ce{H2O + H2O <=> H3O+ + OH-}$

Alternatively, could both meanings apply depending on your perspective?

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: It refers to multiplication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [Zhe's comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67014/what-kind-of-product-is-the-product-in-ionic-product-of-water#comment115838_67014), in the specific context of the term *ionic product of water*, the word *product* is used in the sense of **the result of the mathematical operation of multiplication**:

> The **ionic product of water** equals the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ **times** the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$:
>   $$K_\mathrm w = \ce{[H+][OH-]}$$

(Strictly, per MaxReid's comment, the ionic product water is of course the product of the [*activities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity) of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$, but concentrations are commonly used in routine/non-rigorous calculations as they provide good accuracy for dilute solutions.)

This sense of the word *product* applies any time one is referencing the mathematical description of the equilibrium among the ionic forms of a given species. This usage also includes the [solubility product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_equilibrium#Dissolution_with_dissociation) (again with the above caveat about activities):

> The **solubility product of silver chloride** equals the concentration of $\ce{Ag+}$ **times** the concentration of $\ce{Cl-}$:
>   $$K_\mathrm{sp} = \ce{[Ag+][Cl-]}$$

---

As an aside, note that the main exception to this terminology is when the expression describing the distribution of species requires division by one or more quantities. In this case, the term to use is ***quotient***, for which I expect little ambiguity exists:

> The **reaction quotient** of the reaction
>   $$\ce{A + B->C + D}$$
>   is
>   $$ Q = {\ce{[C][D]}\over \ce{[A][B]}}$$

---

However, to be complete: chemistry does also use the word *product* in the other sense you describe, as in something being *produced* by a reaction.  Due to this, the word *product* in the phrase **the ionic product(s) of X** could also bear this meaning.  For example:

> The **ionic products of the aqueous decomposition of dinitrogen tetroxide** at neutral $\mathrm{pH}$ are nitrite and nitrate ion:
>   $$\ce{N2O4(aq) + 2H2O -> NO2-(aq) + NO3-(aq) + 2H3O+}$$

---

In general, I think the difference boils down to whether one is talking about the ionic distribution of a specific *species* of interest, as opposed to the transformation that occurs in a particular *reaction* of interest.

As I noted above, though: **In the specific case you are asking about, *product* is used in the sense of *the result obtained from multiplication***.

Comment: @PrettyHands Well, now that I think about it -- the answer isn't so cut and dried. See edit.

Comment: @PrettyHands And, well, now that I think about it some more: for the specific case you're asking about, it ***is*** cut and dried. See further edit.

Comment: @hBy2Py Isn't it defined as the product of the thermodynamic activities? In this case it should be equivalent, but for completeness sake I'd like to mention this.

Comment: @MaxRied Strictly, you are of course correct. I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

The **product** $K_w$ is a mathematical construct.

The ion species **produced** from ionization of water are not mathematical constructs. They are resulting entities (actual, tangible "things").

The word *does* have two meanings, but the essence in both cases is "result". There isn't really a case when both meanings would apply to the same "result".

Comment: Thank you. So in the term 'ionic product of water' specifically, it refers to multiplication?

Comment: I think your last paragraph doesn't have the right focus. The gist to me is that just the phrase "ionic product of water" is ambiguous. You have to understand the context in which the phrase is being used to be sure if the mathematical formula, or a chemical species is being discussed. // Needing context is fairly common in English. Look at definition for shoe. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoe

Comment: I agree with Max. Yet the phrase 'ionic product of water' is reserved as the well-known $K_w$.